# Could not find method provided() for arguments [{group=javax.servlet, name=javax.servlet-api, version=3.1.0}]

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am getting the following error:

> Could not find method provided() for arguments [{group=javax.servlet,
>   name=javax.servlet-api, version=3.1.0}]

I have tried several different ways and found people with similar issues but with no avail. I added the below dependency but

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
```

If I remove the `javax.servlet` I am back to the orginal error:

```
Could not find method providedCompile() for arguments [{group=javax.servlet, name=javax.servlet-api, version=3.1.0}]
```

update 1:

new error after adding:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
}
```

error

```
> Could not find javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.1.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/3.1.0/servlet-api-3.1.0.pom
      http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/3.1.0/servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :
```

UPDATE:

I added:

```
allProjects {

    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    group = 'com.lidl.digital.ecom.ratings'

    dependencies {
        compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
    }
}
```

And now the error is:

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'product-rating-parent'.
>
>   > Could not set unknown property 'sourceCompatibility' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

I have seen this error prior to fixing this posted question so I am not sure if it is fixed. When I hover over anything in the gradle file it says `cannot resolve 'whatever I hover over'`

Comment: As a note to the latest update: repositories must be declared within `repositories` block. But in your case `jcenter` and `mavenCentral` are declared in the root of the script. And the error is caused by the `sourceCompatibility` which should be declared after the `java` plugin is applied. Make sure it's not declared before the `allProjects` block in your script.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that you have added your dependency in the wrong place. Dependecies are declared within `dependencies` block as follows

```
dependencies {
    provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
}
```

But in your case it's declared within `repositories`.

Comment: That was a complete over site and embarrassing. Sadly it did not fix the issue.

Could not find method provided() for arguments [{group=javax.servlet, name=javax.servlet-api, version=3.1.0}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.de
pendencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: @Drew1208 As far as I know, there is no such a scope by default. There is `providedCompile` scope, which is available if you use the `war` plugin. In any other cases you have to declare your own scope or use the `compileOnly`scope instead. Here is an explanation haw to use `compileOnly` scope https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies

Comment: I added compileOnly 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.1.0' to the dependencies and get the same error. All modules are complaining about the same thing.

Comment: @Drew1208 could you please update your quiestion and show the whole build configuration as is. And exact exception you've got with `compileOnly`

Comment: It's said that repository you declared doesn't contain this jar. Try to declare some other repository, where this jar is available. For some reason Gradle is looking for it only at the http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between what you report as added and your exception:

> dependencies {
>       compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
>     }

The above is correct, and [exists in Maven Central](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/).

However, your error:

> > Could not find javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.1.0.
> >       Searched in the following locations:
> >           http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/3.1.0/servlet-api-3.1.0.pom
> >           http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/3.1.0/servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
> >       Required by:
> >           project :

It clearly indicates a typo somewhere in the project where the dependency module name is missing the `javax.` part in front of `servlet-api`.

So you must have somewhere code like:

```
dependencies {
  compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
}
```

Notice the missing `javax.` in the name attribute.